# Netflix Conductor type:KAFKA_PUBLISH - Failed to construct kafka producer error

Tags: apache-kafka, netflix-conductor

I have this task created in my workflow:

```
"tasks": [
{
  "name": "get_users_list",
  "taskReferenceName": "get_users_list",
  "inputParameters": {
    "http_request": {
      "uri": "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=${workflow.input.pagenumber}",
      "method": "GET",
      "contentType": "application/json",
      "connectionTimeOut": "36000",
      "readTimeOut": "36000"
    }
  },
  "type": "HTTP",
  "decisionCases": {},
  "defaultCase": [],
  "forkTasks": [],
  "startDelay": 0,
  "joinOn": [],
  "optional": false,
  "defaultExclusiveJoinTask": [],
  "asyncComplete": false,
  "loopOver": []
},
{
  "name": "get_user_details",
  "taskReferenceName": "get_user_details",
  "inputParameters": {
    "http_request": {
      "uri": "https://reqres.in/api/users/${get_users_list.output.response.body.data[0].id}",
      "method": "GET",
      "contentType": "application/json",
      "connectionTimeOut": "36000",
      "readTimeOut": "36000"
    }
  },
  "type": "HTTP",
  "decisionCases": {},
  "defaultCase": [],
  "forkTasks": [],
  "startDelay": 0,
  "joinOn": [],
  "optional": false,
  "defaultExclusiveJoinTask": [],
  "asyncComplete": false,
  "loopOver": []
},
{
  "name": "call_kafka",
  "taskReferenceName": "call_kafka",
  "inputParameters": {
    "kafka_request": {
      "topic": "transaction-1",
      "value": "${get_user_details.output.response.body.data.first_name}",
      "bootStrapServers": "kafka:9092"
    },
    "key": "",
    "keySerializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer"
  },
  "type": "KAFKA_PUBLISH",
  "decisionCases": {},
  "defaultCase": [],
  "forkTasks": [],
  "startDelay": 0,
  "joinOn": [],
  "optional": false,
  "defaultExclusiveJoinTask": [],
  "asyncComplete": false,
  "loopOver": []
}
```

],

When first two tasks are COMPLETED and the "call_kafka" task is getting failed with this error,

> "Failed to invoke kafka task due to:
> org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka
> producer"

I am new to Netflix Conductor and trying to publish a message to Kafka through workflow. Please correct me if anything wrong and suggest a solution for this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Kafka task has been moved to community repo.
Please check: https://github.com/Netflix/conductor/discussions/2961

Resolved by: Adding the below dependency in `conductor/server/build.gradle` file:

implementation `com.netflix.conductor:conductor-kafka:3.8.0`